# Open page from WebBrowser1 in WebBrowser2 in D7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am developing a webbrowser in Delphi 7 and I want to open every action of one browser (WB1) in another webbrowser (WB2). For a hyperlink I used the event OnBeforeNavigate2, cancelled the navigation in WB1 and used the var URL to navigate in WB2. However, when a have a page with a Button or a droplist with an action I don't have an URL to open in WB2. So, does anyone know a way to open every action from WB1 in WB2??

Comment: What actions are you trying to catch exactly? Any attempt to navigate to a new URL is going to trigger the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event. But things that are tied to scripts, like OnClick events, will not. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to develop my own system of history in the webbrowser. For that I would build a var array and create webbrowser everytime people opened a new webpage (even OnClick event) and this page would be loaded in the new WebBrowser. So, when people wanted to come back to the old page, or come back to the first page they accessed, I would destroy the webbrowser. It would be faster and also it would avoid losing page when they are not stored in cache. I think it is how chrome does it, so I think it is possible, do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks!